# Adding Boolean or Tag to Image File Field

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I am using [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) and have added a boolean to the image file field. This checkbox is to check when I want to make a favourite photo.

My problem is, I'm not seeing this on the node creation page, I upload the image(s) and I just still have alt and title fields available and no boolean.

I have gone through manage form display, manage display and I can see it there for Default and Thumbnail view modes.

What step am I missing?

Drupal 8

Answer (score 0):

The module File Entity has it's own field widget "Editable file".

You have to change the image field to use this widget in manage form display of the content type.

Then add a new image in the node creation page and a button will appear to edit the custom fields inline.

The widget has no preview image. So you have to choose, if you want inline fields or preview images.

The File Entity module is a basic solution with a very simple user interface.

A complete media solution for D8 will be provided by the [Drupal Media Initiative](http://www.drupalmedia.org/), here are the latest news:

http://janezurevc.name/releases-of-various-drupal-8-media-modules

Comment: 4k4 thank you for your input! It seems I go tthat far, when I click on Edit on the manage form display for the image it loads but nothing happens and then just shows the image filename with the edit and remove buttons to the right....

Comment: Don't understand, on the manage form display you only configure the field, you can't load the image filename there, this is in the node add form.

Comment: I think you are already on the node add form, when you have edit and remove to the right of the filename. Click on the edit button and this will open a popup with the custom fields.

Comment: I click on edit and nothing happens.... So it looks like I'm doing everything right, there is just an error somewhere. Thanks for all your help 4k4! I can hopefully sort this error out and get this working.

Comment: try it with a fresh install